# Laravel 4 add User and Child

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am writing a web app where there are users with different account types and roles. The DB is set up in such a way where there is a Users table and then a Customers table which carries the related user_id.

I have set up the relationship with the Users Eloquent model and the Customers Eloquent model so the fetching of records works properly.

I was wondering however if there is a way within Laravel to apply the same logic for inserting or updating. For example, I am adding a new customer to the db. This requires adding certain data to the Users table and then certain data to the Customers table. Is there a smart way to do this in Laravel instead of adding the user data and then making sure the data was added before adding the customer as the relationship is already defined?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can do it by using [Fluent](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve? Perhaps some examples? From what I understand if you want to do it using Eloquent, you will somehow still need to save one of the first in order to create an `id` that will be referenced as a foreign key the other table.

Comment: Yea that is what I thought, I was just wondering it is was possible to auto populate the customer record based on the fact that I am adding a user and know the type.